# No data in the response body

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return some JSON data from my controller. I actually got it working with.

`response()->json(['success'=>true])->send();`

but that is not the way it's done in the documentation. I tried

`return \Response::json(['success' => true]);`

and the status code was 200 but no data in the body. I guess it's okay but I just really want to know what the problem is. There were nothing in the log so there does not seem to be an error. If it's any help, I'm using Laravel 5.5.40 and a dependency called tymon/jwt-auth which applies some middleware for auth and refresh.

Should probably add that I have tried to simply return an array and string but the result stays the same.

**CONTROLLER**
*Notice the commented section in createGame*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Game;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class GameController extends Controller
{
public function getPostPatchDelete(Request $req){

    switch($req->method()){
        case 'GET':
            $this->getGame($req);
        case 'POST':    
            $this->createGame($req);
        case 'PATCH':
            $this->updateGame($req);
        case 'DELETE':
            $this->deleteGame($req);
    }
}

private function getGame($req){

}
private function createGame($req){
    //Response::json(['success' => 'hi, atiq']);
    //return response()->json(['lel'=>'lol'], 200);        
    response()->json(['success'=>true])->send(); 
}
private function updateGame($req){

}
private function deleteGame($req){

}
```

}

Comment: did you add any middleware?

Comment: Ẃell no, not any besides the ones I mentioned.

Comment: Double checked and I have another middleware Barryvdh\Cors but there is no difference when I remove it.

Comment: can you show the controller implementation?

Comment: you forgot to use `return` in functions.

Comment: I'm only calling createGame since I'm making a POST request. Also look at the commented returns.

Comment: Why don't you route each method (GET/POST) to each function in route.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `return` in `getPostPatchDelete()` AND `createGame()`:

```
public function getPostPatchDelete(Request $req){
    switch($req->method()){
        case 'POST':    
            return $this->createGame($req);
    }
}

private function createGame($req){
    return response()->json(['success'=>true]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I always do it is like this:

```php
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Some message.'], 200);
```

Note: the second argument of the `json()` function is the status code.

---

Of course is always nice to use descriptive constants instead of numbers -in this case to set the HTTP response code- so:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class CoolController extends Controller {


    public function coolFunction() {

        // your logic

        return response()->json(['message' => 'A message.'], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at createGame you can see that I have commented a two versions of responding. One of which is exactly what you wrote.

Comment: I have not denied that. Just stating that using the helper is not a bad way to do it. On the other hand, is not "exactly" the way you do it: I just return it directly without calling the `send()` method.

Comment: Might be too tired but I think you are missing this //return response()->json(['lel'=>'lol'], 200);